# Problem with frequency analysis of user input array in C

Tags: c

I'm supposed to do a freqency analysis of a user input array. User may enter as many numbers between 0-1000 as s/he wants and a maximum of 100 numbers can be entered, user ends input by entering a negative number. A void function will calculate which number appears the most times and those 2 variables should be sent to the function as pointers.

My problem is that no matter what I do the analysis seems to calculate all the "empty" elements of the array and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. If i make the array smaller to lets say 10 elements it works fine. As I'm a complete novice when it comes to programming and I've changed the code about a million times so at this point I can't remeber what I've changed from my original code. When debugging I get stuck in the second for loop in the function..

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100
#define INTERVAL 1000

void frequencyAnalysis(int array[],int *number, int *freq)
{
    int element = 0, count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        int tempElement = array[i];
        int tempCount = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
            if (array[j] == tempElement)
                tempCount++;

        if (tempCount > count) {
            element = tempElement;
            count = tempCount;
        }
    }

    *number = element; 
    *freq = count;
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[MAX], i, j, number = 0, freq = 0;

    printf("Hello.\n"
        "Please enter a number between 0-1000. "
        "Enter as many number as you want (maximum 100).\n"
        "Exit by entering a negative number.\n\n");
    printf("Enter a number:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        if (array[i] < 0)
            break;
    }

    frequencyAnalysis(array, &number, &freq);

    printf("The number:%d is the most frequent number and appears %d times.\n", number, freq);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I've fixed them now..

Comment: Your code is running through the entire array (up to MAX) even if the user doesn't enter that many items, and the initial value of every array element is going to be random junk from the stack.  Perhaps consider passing in to the analysis how many numbers it should look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the first issue, pass in how many items the user actually entered so you're not running up to `MAX` (which would include all the unused cells). The key is `nitems`.

```
void frequencyAnalysis(int array[], int nitems, int *number, int *freq)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nitems; i++) {
        ...
        for (int j = 0; j < nitems; j++)
        {
           // do stuff
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
int array[MAX],i, j, number = 0, freq = 0;

    ...
    frequencyAnalysis(array, i, &number,&freq);
    ///
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to figure out how to only use the entered values all day long. I knew it would be easy but I just couldn't do it.

Comment: Also recommend that you use the result of `scanf()` to help you end the loop. It returns the number of items correctly converted, so if they type `abc` then that's bogus input that should end the loop as well.   `if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1  ||  array[i] < 0) break;`

Comment: Thank you ever so much!